# Purple/violet and blue mixture lens effect around Lobelia Erinus flower

Tags: effect, camera, color-blue, flowers, color-violet

I was only wondering why is this effect on center of lens different than around it.
Realme 5 phoen camera.[image: Lobelia Flower]

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7sdj.jpg) of how I move the phone and the effect is always the same ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7sdj.jpg

Comment: Are all of these flowers supposed to be the same color?

Answer (score 1):

From a [camera review](https://www.gsmarena.com/realme_5-review-1990p5.php):

> The camera app offers AI scene recognition - you'll see a small icon when a scene is successfully recognized, and the software will tweak all settings accordingly. Food, snow, pets, sunsets, grass, among other scenes, are detected mostly correctly.

So this is possibly a case where the "mostly" in "mostly correctly' applies. The scene isn't recognized properly and the camera applies the wrong tweaks (for instance adding some red for better skin tones). What is the scene icon? Can you disable this (or use a different camera app)?

Comment: Thanks, that day I Remember that I used some effect on videos, but not on photos, but it could be that simple camera is AI'ed. I will try though using Camera Pro on phone, Wich is the last option that I don't use often, only when there is some focus lack. I will check it, and post again trying even with another phone.